# Chart not displaying all values

Tags: c#, charts

I have a database, I am querying this database and take some query values from database and then I plot this values with visual studio chart control. But not display all values in my query. For example:

```
Query = { A, B, C , D , E , F }
```

Chart:

```
 F  |
    |
 C  |
    |
 B  |
    |
    |__________________________________
    1     3      5        9       13
```

There are only three values in this chart. But I want all values to be showed in this chart.

I try this, But does not work:

```
Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 1;
```

Code :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)            
{
    panel1.Visible = false;
    chart2.Series["Seçilen Gün"].Points.DataBindXY(myList, dblArray);
    chart2.Series["Aylık Ortalama"].Points.DataBindXY(myList, dblArray2);
}
```

List query some this:

```
myList = {"JOB_A", "JOB_B", "JOB_C", "JOB_D" }
dblArray = {"12:00, "23:11", 16:31", "18:34"}
```

Comment: dblArray contains strings? how they are converted to numbers? Isn't it supposed to be 12.00, for example?

Comment: Contains String. Cast to double   
                                      
       dblArray[ir] = Convert.ToDouble(c.ToString());

Answer (score 3):

*This answer was provided by the OP, but he mistakenly posted it as a comment.*

```
Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 1;
```